# Sliding View in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am developing an android vocab app. My requirement is that when word moves to another word. The transition should be like sliding. I am displaying word in textView.

I want to implement a sliding behaviour to the textView when text value changes.

It should behaves like a page truning or sliding.

Comment: yes.  clear the requirement more clear and programming specific

Comment: Let me know if i am clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554685/how-to-animate-a-fadeout-and-fadein-while-textview-changed-text). You can set animations to TextSwitcher.